# Как построить спектрограмму в C#?

Tags: c#

Подскажите, есть ли готовые библиотеки для построения спектрограммы (пример ниже), по данным двумерного массива. Для преобразования данных из массива нужна цветовая карта (цвет - значение)? Язык C# (WPF или WinForms)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что показывает данное изображение? Вот то, что обычно называют спектрограммой: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Спектрограмма

Comment: Это просто пример. Обычный набор чисел (3,2,1), где за каждым числом закрепляется какой-то цвет (3 - красный, 2 - зеленый, 1 - синий), и выводится в координатную ось.

Comment: Может что-то из этого вам поможет https://habr.com/post/204308/